# Django Form Preview with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms

I still didn't get django form preview with google app engine to work. I didn't see a working example and my attempts to use django form preview with google app engine failed since I couldn't translate the request handler usage from django to gae. I'm getting a form preview but it won't render:

```
        <html><body><form method="POST" action="/preview">
    <table>
<django.contrib.formtools.preview.FormPreview object at 0x3c5ca50>
    </table><input type="submit"></form></body></html>
```

The code that generates the HTML above is:

```
import cgi

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms

class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    target_price = db.FloatProperty()
    priority = db.StringProperty(default='Medium',choices=[
      'High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
    entry_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = db.UserProperty()

class ItemForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['added_by']

from django.contrib.formtools.preview import FormPreview
class PreviewHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                '<form method="POST" '
                                'action="/preview">'
                                '<table>')
        self.response.out.write(FormPreview(ItemForm()))
        self.response.out.write('</table>'                                    
                                '<input type="submit">'
                                '</form></body></html>')



class ItemPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY name")
        for item in query:
            self.response.out.write('<a href="/edit?id=%d">Edit</a> - ' %
                                    item.key().id())
            self.response.out.write("%s - Need to buy %d, cost $%0.2f each<br>" %
                                    (item.name, item.quantity, item.target_price))

class EditPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        id = int(self.request.get('id'))
        item = Item.get(db.Key.from_path('Item', id))
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                '<form method="POST" '
                                'action="/edit">'
                                '<table>')
        self.response.out.write(ItemForm(instance=item))
        self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                '<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="%s">'
                                '<input type="submit">'
                                '</form></body></html>' % id)

    def post(self):
      id = int(self.request.get('_id'))
      item = Item.get(db.Key.from_path('Item', id))
      data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST, instance=item)
      if data.is_valid():
          # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
          entity = data.save(commit=False)
          entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
          entity.put()
          self.redirect('/items.html')
      else:
          # Reprint the form
          self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                  '<form method="POST" '
                                  'action="/edit">'
                                  '<table>')
          self.response.out.write(data)
          self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                  '<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="%s">'
                                  '<input type="submit">'
                                  '</form></body></html>' % id)

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                         [('/', PreviewHandler),
                                          ('/edit', EditPage),
                                          ('/items.html', ItemPage),
                                          ],
                                         debug=True)

    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

How should I implement the PreviewHandler?
Thank you in advance

UPDATE: Since django has form preview, could I take the template from the django framework and built on it or make my own template? For instance how ta enable that user presses the back button to make changes that also should initiate a validation

```
<input type="button" value="&lt;-- Go back" name="back" onClick="history.back()" />

<input type="submit" name="validate" value='{% trans "Go" %}' />
```

Comment: Why aren't you using templates?

Comment: I didn't have a session and for preview I think it needs a session object (I can use beaker sessions) and I can use templates instead but I wanted the most high-level solution that I think is using a preview already implemented. Now it looks though as I'm going to implement preview using beaker session + templates for a form that's larger than trivial - it's also posting blobs

Comment: ...I don't see what any of that has to do with using templates.

Comment: Thank you Nick for the comment. I created a template preview.html but I don't fully understand how to use it since I want some extras that I didn't mention like handling passwords and timing out added entities that were not published and just left by the user after the first submit. So I suppose I should add another variable to indicate whether the item is published and it seemed to violate the DRY principle when there is already use cases implemented doing form preview. The major additionals I'm going to handle are blobs and passwords for items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django documentation for FormPreview can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/). It makes it clear that FormPreview is intended to be subclassed and used as a handler, which you can't do in webapp - it's specific to the Django framework. You certainly can't just instantiate a `FormPreview` object with your form and expect the string representation to be useful.